# How to improve network delay in nextjs project

Tags: optimization, next.js

while doing inspecting my next.js project, I dont get it why there is network idle time below network graph..

[image]

[image]
at time from 450ms ~ 800ms there is huge time delay... any ideas of this?

and is there any suggestions that I can make this much faster?

right now Im using SSG to render page

Answer (score 0):

Try inspecting your production bundle instead of development (run `next build && next start`). Development build will always be slower.

Also check if you haven't set up throttling in the devTools.
[image]